# nested routing in angular changes the outer component

Tags: angular

I have the following angular app structure:

```
app.component.html -> startpage.component.html -> layout.component.html.
```

Which means the following: in the `app.component.html` I have a simple `router-outlet` (nothing else). If the users logs in, the app redirects to the `startpage` component. For this I have this in the `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
...
  {
    path: 'startpage', component: StartPageComponent, children: [
    ]
  }
...
```

In the `startpage` component I have the `layout` component (nothing else):

```
<layout></layout>
```

This `layout` component consists of a drawer with a sidebar and a header inside it like this:

```
<dx-drawer id="drawer"
           #drawer
           [(opened)]="isDrawerOpen"
           openedStateMode="shrink"
           revealMode="slide"
           [closeOnOutsideClick]="true"
           template="mainmenu"
           (onOptionChanged)="toggled()">
  <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'mainmenu'">
    <app-sidebar #sidebar (itemClicked)="onItemClick($event)"></app-sidebar>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <app-header (hamburgerClicked)="onHamburgerClick()" (settingsClicked)="onSettingsClick()" (userClicked)="onUserClick()"></app-header>
    <div id="view" class="dx-theme-background-color"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
  </div>
</dx-drawer>
```

As you see, there is an other `router-outlet`.

The goal is, if the user clicks in the sidebar on a menu element, it shows the corresponding component. For this I have f. e. this in the `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
...
{
    path: 'masterdata', component: StartPageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'general', component: MdGeneralComponent },
      { path: 'costaccounting', component: MdCostAccountingComponent },
      { path: 'prodplanning', component: MdProdPlanningComponent }
    ],
  }
...
```

It works, but with an issue. In my app, the user can select some skins. Depending on the skin, the `app-header` gets an other color. It works too. But if I click in the sidebar on an other element, the header gets the default skin settings. It is, because the `startpage.component` gets loaded again and it loses the settings. But if I don't give a component to the `masterdata`, there is no header and sidebar anymore, just the clicked component (f. e. `MdGeneralComponent`).

My goal is to avoid this reload of the `startpage.component`. Which means, on each and every click on a sidebar element only the `router-outlet` on the 2. level gets changed and the `startpage.component` (and so the `layout.component`) remains the same.

How to do that? I have experimented with the `app-routing.module.ts`, but no success.

Comment: Not 100% if I understand you correctly.. but why not have the layout component inside app-component.html, together with your routing outlet?

Comment: Yes, I had this and it worked as expected. But then I added the login feature and for this I needed an 'entry point'. I mean, after login I need a redirect. But I have a new idea.

Comment: Ah right. In that case, you can move your router-outlet to a deeper level so you can still have a login without layout..? Does that make sense?